# Draco not making the "qsg" database in Docker

Tags: docker, fiware

I am very new to docker and fiware/draco. I am following this documentation: https://github.com/ging/fiware-draco/blob/master/docs/quick_start_guide.md

The problem is that Draco will not create the "qsg" database.
This is my docker terminal:

[image]

I followed this documentation step by step but I don't see where the error is.

This is how it's supposed to look:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm it works. Please follow the steps in the tutorial correctly. Once you have the flow working (green triangles and no errors) you can send the notification like in the example. At that point the new schema will be created.

[image]

[image]